# Firebase Packages called within Custom Packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working on custom packages we use internally in our organization and I'm trying to reduce how many properties I need to pass into the Component I'm creating for the package. One of the components I'm building involve firebase/storage. I want to only pass the result of `getStorage()` from my app and let the package import `ref`, `uploadBytes`, etc. I don't want to have to import them individually and pass them as props. However, whenever I try to import `ref` in the package and call `ref(storage)`, it returns the FirebaseStorageImpl again, not the StorageReference I expect.

Some code from the compiled package:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ref, uploadBytes, deleteObject } from 'firebase/storage';
export const Files = (props) => {
  const {
    storage
  } = props;
  console.log(
    storage,
    ref(storage)
  );
}
```

And my application file:

```
import { React } from 'react';
import { Files } from 'my-package';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

const App = () => {
    const firebaseApp = initializeApp(/* FIREBASE CONFIG */);
    const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
    return (<Files
        storage={storage}
    />)
}
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your console output? It does log a reference for me with same code. (Firebase version `9.6.7`)

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/M2RKmUmdjF7T.png I logged  `storage` and `ref(storage)` in the AppJS and PackageJS files

Comment: Saw something similar in a package of my own.    The workaround for me was to pass down the `ref` function imported from firebase/storage in the parent app as a parameter to the imported package and then run *that* `ref()` inside the imported package's code.  I'll post a proper answer when I've got more info, but I've only just discovered this.

Comment: As promised, sample repo here https://bitbucket.org/bludgeco/firebase-storage-import-demo/src/main/.